# How can I create a wallet and display the address, public and private key using web3js?

Tags: web3js, wallets, accounts, addresses, infura

I am using this as my source for web3js:

```
<script src="http://raw.githubusercontent.com/ethereum/web3.js/0.16.0/dist/web3.min.js">
    </script>
```

In my HTML I want to display the account's address on the page and tried by the following code:

```
<p id="accountAddress">
        <script>
            web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://mainnet.infura.io/MYTOKENKEY"));
            var wallet = web3.eth.accounts.create([entropy]);
            document.write('new wallet address ' + wallet.accounts[0]);
            document.getElementById("accountAddress").innerHTML = wallet.accounts[0];
        </script>
    </p>
```

But nothing displays.

I can't find in the documentation on how to create wallets and display information associated with them so any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The parameters you need are `address` and `privateKey` of the object `account`. [See the docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-accounts.html#create)

You can create the account doing:

```
var newAccount = web3.eth.accounts.create([entropy]);
```

Then, you can get the address and the privateKey like this:

```
var address = newAccount.address
var privateKey = newAccount.privateKey
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'm still having trouble getting it to display anything. I've uploaded my whole code of what I have now here https://pastebin.com/21WzQMkN . I was following the Infura tutorial but then decided to try and add a bit that creates an account and displays the info for it. I tried using the help you gave me and info from the docs but it doesn't do anything. Maybe you can see where I am going wrong in my code? Thanks again for helping.

Comment: The issue seems to be with the web3 version you can do this with 1.0 and you are using 0.1x

Comment: Do you know the url I should use for the script @ <script src="http://raw.githubusercontent.com/ethereum/web3.js/0.16.0/dist/web3.min.js">
    </script> for the web3js 1.0 , also the docs say 1.0 is in development and not yet implemented, is that a problem or just something they say for liability in the docs?

Comment: You could install web3 uisng mpn but if it is not stable is better not to use it. You can use other libraries to generate the account as this is not related to the nodes. For instance, [keyethereum](https://github.com/ethereumjs/keythereum) the examples in the link show how to add the *.js files and create accounts.